# Jest snapshot is null after react instance is updated

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-test-renderer

I would like to register a snapshot of a component after a button onPress function is run.

This is my testsuite:

```js
describe('Login component', () => {
    // This runs fine. Snapshot OK
    it('Renders correctly', () => {
        const tree = renderer.create(<Login />).toJSON()
        expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()
    })

    // This does not run fine. Snapshot is 'null'
    it('Contains error message when submit with empty fields', () => {
        const login = renderer.create(<Login />)
        const instance = login.getInstance()

        // Submit the form (default values = empty)
        instance.submit()

        // Force update (rerender) the component
        login.update()
        expect(login.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot()

    })
})
```

The testsuite above creates two snapshots. The first test snapshots the component's structure under default conditions, and seems to register correctly.

The second test should record the component structure after a submit has been run, showing error messages alerting the user that the form cannot be submitted with empty fields.

Unfortunately this does not work as expected as after `login.update()` is run, `login.toJSON()` returns `null`.

I'm obviously doing something wrong, but what? [The docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/test-renderer.html#testrendererupdate) seem to indicate that `update` does what I think it does.

Comment: you have to call login.update(<Login />) instead of login.update()

Comment: Thank you @AshKander this is the correct answer! Why post it as a comment? :)